# identifying structure members dynamically

Tags: c

is there any possible ways to inspect a structure members at runtime?

For example consider the code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct example{
    int value;
    char name[32];
    int score;
};

int main()
{
    char in[256]={};

    printf("enter member name :\n");
    scanf("%s",in);

    if(check_member(in) == 1) {
        printf("struct example has member %s \n,in);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("struct example has no member named %s \n,in);
    return -1;
}
```

if I input `value` to this program, it should print

> struct example has member value

And when I input `test` to this program it should print

> struct example has no member named test

Is there any possible way to write function `check_member()` ?

Comment: C doesn't have [type introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) so no that's not possible. If you try to explain *why* you need this, what the *actual* problem you want to solve is, then perhaps we can help you with that instead? Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Basically, no, not easily. But it might technically be possible if you build for debug and (somehow) call debugging functions which might allow introspection because theu can access the debug info from the binary.

Comment: Since you know the structure of the type, it is possible to achieve the desired output for the shown sample input: pseudo code `if "value" or "name" or "core" print "yes" else print "no" `.

Comment: Please show the complete prototype of `check_member()`. How is the input available? How is the struct selected? How is the result communicated? Boolean return value? Printf of the shown text?

Comment: Do a web search on, as Some programmer dude suggested, "type introspection" or "reflection".  This will confirm that C doesn't have it, but you'll probably find lots of tips on how people have accomplished similar things in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, because after compilation the names of the variables are not being saved in the memory of the stack only their locations so there is no way to get the data in runtime.
Of course as @Yunnosch said you can save the names of the members in string and then use strcmp.

Comment: It is possible, see my comment. Only if you assume additional restriction, which OP has not described, it is impossible...

Comment: yes, but then you compare the string of the input to other string. I thought his question was is there a way to find the name of struct member without creating a string variable.

Comment: Yes, assuming that is not allowed is the assumption I mean. It is not defined in the question, is it?

Answer (score 2):

There are probably lots of duplicate answers on this.  If I had to do this I would approach it one of two ways:

1. I would build my own little dictionary of structure member names, their offsets, and perhaps their types.  I would use the standard `offsetof()` macro to manipulate the offsets.  Maintaining the dictionary would be a nuisance (especially if adding or removing members from the structure were likely to be frequent), but unavoidable.  I would resist the temptation to use preprocessor tricks to "ease" the maintenance of the struct and dictionary definitions, because those tend to just be more confusing in the long run.
2. I wouldn't use a C `struct` at all, but would implement my own associative array (probably using a hash table).

Oh, wait, one more:

3. I would use an [interface definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to automatically generate both my struct declarations, and my run-time dictionary definition, from a single, higher-level data description.